# Use JDBCTemplate in spring framework

Tags: spring, groovy

I want to add actualEffort group by projet_id for that I tried below code but in code getJdbcTemplate,queryForObject showing underlined even I have imported package called

```
import javax.sql.DataSource

import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
```

coding

```
public int findTotal(){
    String sql = "select sum(actual_effort) from task group by project_id";
    int total = getJdbcTemplate().queryForInt(sql);
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a `getJdbcTemplate` method?  Does the code work?  DO you get an exception?  What is the error?

Comment: sorry I do not have  getJdbcTemplate method I need to create if yes then tell me how

Comment: You say `queryForObject` is underlined but your code has `queryForInt`.

Comment: Also, is this groovy?  The above looks like Java?

Comment: sorry I don't know much but I should be int only If other then plz tell me I will change

Comment: In groovy in other whatever u want plz tell me correct difficulty to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since it seems that you are using spring you can use something like:

```
public class YourClass {

  @Autowired  
  DataSource dataSource;

  JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

  public YourClass(){
      jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);
  }

  public int findTotal(){
    String sql = "select sum(actual_effort) from task group by project_id";
    int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
    return total;
  }
}
```

And in your spring config you must create the `dataSource` bean with your data base information:

```
<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="XXXX.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:XXXX />
    <property name="username" value="XXX" />
    <property name="password" value="XXX" />
</bean>
```

**EDIT**

After review your question I'm not sure if you're interested on use spring `jdbcTemplate` facility or you simply want to make a query using groovy ... if your case is the second instead of using `jdbcTemplate` simply use groovy facilities from `groovy.sql.Sql` to do so, for example:

```
import groovy.sql.Sql;

def db = [
    url : 'jdbc:XXXXX',
    username : 'XXX',
    password : 'XXXX',
    driver : 'XXXXXXX'
]

def sql = Sql.newInstance("${db.url}", "${db.username}", "${db.password}","${db.driver}")

def result = sql.executeQuery('select sum(actual_effort) from task group by project_id')
println (result.getInt('sum(actual_effort)'))
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: No DataSource specified error is coming in application.properties I have written this config coding.

Comment: @LokeshKumarGaurav sorry I don't understand your comment however I update my answer with a alternative way which I think it could be useful `:)`

Comment: You shouldn't create a `JdbcTemplate` just because you need one, it is a heavy object to create. Create it once and reuse.

Comment: @M.Deinum it was only a sample, however you're right, I update my answer thanks `:)`

Comment: Groovy has nothing like `{url: "jdbc:XXXXX"}` as syntax, if you want to create a Map (or HashMap) you must use brackets instead `[url: "jdbc:XXXXX"]` instead, curly braces is reserved to create a `Closure` in groovy.

Comment: Thanks @bitsnaps you're right, probably I typed the code without testing it.

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

```
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;

public int findTotal(){
String sql = "select sum(actual_effort) from task group by project_id";
JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate();

int total = jdbcTemplate.queryForInt(sql);
return total;
}
```